# Retrieve data from different tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to retrieve data from two tables like below. I have a `Products` table which has `P_id`, `P_name` columns and a `BATCH` table with `p_id_fk` as a foreign key to the `Products` table.

This is my query; I want to retrieved from product's name from the `Product` table because I have stored the `Products` table primary key as a foreign in the `Batch` table.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id, quantity, left_qty, purchaseDate, manufacturing_date, expiryDate from batch where Convert(DATE, expiryDate, 103) BETWEEN @from AND @to", con);

sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: What are you getting for an error / exception? You mention querying two tables, but I only see one.

Comment: So, are you asking how to do a `JOIN`? A `JOIN` is one of the fundamentals in SQL, you can read about them in the documentation: [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017). I suggest have a read, as it's a core requirement if you want to write any kind of SQL, including T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a join or cross apply here.

**Option 1 - inner join:**

```
    Select         
    b.batch_id,pd.product_name,quantity,left_qty,
    purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch b 
    inner join product pd on pd.p_id = b.p_id  where Convert(DATE,expiryDate,103) 
    BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

**Option 2 cross apply:**

```
    Select         
    b.batch_id,pd.product_name,quantity,left_qty,
    purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch b 
    cross apply
    (
     select product_name from product p
     where p.p_id = b.p_id
    ) pd
    where Convert(DATE,expiryDate,103) 
    BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

for more about cross apply look [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/).

Comment: it is not like what i want, i want that Product_name to be retrieved from Products table. Batch table has column named p_id_fk which is foreign key column and contains values of Products.

Comment: this is exactly what you need to do, join between the tables, then you get product_name from products table.

Comment: I have tried but it is giving error on "pd.product_name" that it is an invalid object

Comment: then you need to check that the column exists in products table and that the inner join points to the right table :)

Comment: Thanks actually, in Datagrid binding i had written wrong binding name and it was not showing names. So now it is working. Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve data from two tables you need to use a SQL JOIN

I am not sure of the exact make up of your tables but something like the below

```
Select batch_id,
product_name,
quantity,
left_qty,
purchaseDate,
manufacturing_date,
expiryDate
from batch B
INNER JOIN Products P
ON P.P_id = B.P_id
where Convert(DATE,expiryDate,103) BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

Comment: It is not like what i want, i want to get Product_name from Products table,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I believe for your query you are looking for something simple as JOIN between `Products` and `Batch` tables:

```
SELECT
    P.P_id,
    P.P_name,
    B.batch_id,
    B.product_name,
    B.quantity,
    B.left_qty,
    B.purchaseDate,
    B.manufacturing_date,
    B.expiryDate
FROM Batch AS B
INNER JOIN Products AS P
ON B.p_id_fk = P.P_id
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, B.expiryDate, 103) BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

`p_id_fk` name you provided might be not an actual column name in `Batch` table but rather the name of the foreign key constraint itself as it appears by the naming convention (`_fk` suffix).